# How to make a htaccess redirection when a WP is living there?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Let's imagine I have somedomain.com and in the root, I have a standard \index.php that opens an online service I've developed.

Also, I have a folder called \wpress that opens a Wordpress Site, so when I go to

somedomain.com/index.php opens my online tool, no problem
somedomain.com/wpress opens my Wordpress, no problem

What I need to do is, to avoid giving a weird address with an .PHP implied, I would like to have something like this:

somedomain.com/tool or somedomain.com/tool/ and then a redirection is done to somedomain.com/index.php

I've tried but sometimes WP takes control... Weird...

```
-------------------------------
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /tool$ /index.php

#This zone is to redirect to WP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wpress [L,QSA]

--------------------------------
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help will be GREAT you htaccess gurus!

Comment: If you don't want to see the `index.php` in the URL, then it of course makes no sense that you are trying to explicitly _redirect_ to it.

Comment: Nono, I don't care to see somedomain.com/index.php at all, once it has been redirected from /tool/ or /tool

Comment: Then you mustn't do a redirect, but an internal rewrite only.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but with the code I wrote, if I go to /tool, it jumps to /wpress... That's why I'm asking for help

Comment: You need to use a RewriteRule for this, Redirect will always cause an external redirect.